# Why does this list have an error?

Tags: java, awt

I am following a tutorial on YouTube, making a Java game.

And I'm getting this error while following it, and I have no idea as to why.

```
The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Enemy>
```

Here's the list:

```
private List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
```

I have imported `java.util.*;` and `java.awt.*;` for List to, theoretically, work.

Here is my Enemy class

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Enemy extends Entity {

    private Rectangle hitbox;
    private int movementX, movementY;
    private boolean dead = false;
    private Main instance;

    public Enemy(Main instance, int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
        this.instance = instance;
        hitbox = new Rectangle(x,y,32,32);

        movementX = 0;
        movementY = 1;
    }

    private void move(){
        if(instance.getStage().isCollided(hitbox)){
            movementY = 0;
            dead = true;
        }
        hitbox.x += movementX;
        hitbox.y += movementY;
    }

    public boolean isDead() { return dead; }


    public void draw(Graphics g){
        move();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(hitbox.x, hitbox.y, hitbox.width, hitbox.height);
    }

}
```

Comment: wrong import most likely, try using `private java.util.List<Enemy> enemies`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have only imported `java.awt.*`, which has a different non-generic `List`.  You must fully-qualify your reference to `java.util.List` because `java.awt.List` is imported.

```
private java.util.List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
```

Ensure that you have `java.util.*` imported so `ArrayList` is resolved also.

Comment: Ah yes, thankyou very much :) Didn't know that. Will tick in 9 mins

Comment: @SebastianA This is the exact reason why wildcard imports aren't recommended.

Comment: @chrylis I see now! I just thought it was a faster way of importing things... Seems not :(

Comment: @SebastianA It was, back in the ancient days before IDEs. Now, use an IDE, and it'll manage all of that for you.

Comment: This is why wildcard imports are a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

By importing `java.awt.*`, you are also importing `java.awt.List`. You probably wanted to use `java.util.List` instead of `java.awt.List`.

Replace the wildcard import from `java.awt` with separate `import` statements for all the classes you need from `java.awt`, and import `java.util.List`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is compiler is trying to treat this List object as java.awt.List not java.util.List. Replace the code with

```
private java.util.List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
```